# Credit scoring data

Tags: data-request

Doing some research on credit scoring models, and realizing that I need real world data about people's credit default. Something like their age/employing years/debth/income with default fact.

Comment: You might ask creditkarma.com creditsesame.com or even the major credit bureaus if they're willing to sell you this information. I don't think you'll find it for free.

Comment: http://www.statistik.lmu.de/service/datenarchiv/kredit/kredit_e.html
Here i found some data, so its not impossible, Its still actual.